# Python: Start and stop timer

Tags: python, timer

I have a code which runs for more than 1,000 iterations. I want te implement a timer that starts before the code starts executing and stops after the execution of the code is done. By this i simply want to measure the time taken for the code to complete the iterations. How do I implement such a timer in python?

**Code Structure:**

Start timer

//Code

Stop Timer

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's an answer to the same question you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2866456/4380308

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
code_block
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0
```

Or you can use the 'timeit' module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2866460/4380308

```
timeit.timeit('foobar()', number=1000)
```

Comment: if you see a duplicate you should flag it as one