# Which is faster? if not x in OR if x not in

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, optimization

```
if not 7 in [5, 6, 7]:
     # something

if 7 not in [5, 6, 7]:
    # something
```

Which is faster?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is the kind of question you could easily test for yourself. Have you tried `timeit` or some other mechanism to test both those lines on your machine?

Comment: Only a matter of readability and personal choice.

Comment: When in doubt, *measure*. Run a loop a couple of million times for each variant, and measure the total time of the loops. Compare the results. See e.g. [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866380/how-can-i-time-a-code-segment-for-testing-performance-with-pythons-timeit) for examples on how to do the timing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are exactly the same, and thus take the same amount of time. `not in` is just syntactic sugar. Using the `dis` module, we can see that both result in the same bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis("not x in y")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("x not in y")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Even adding parentheses as `not (x in y)` does not change that, unless, of course, you add more to the parentheses:

```
>>> dis.dis("not (x in y)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("not (x in y or z)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (y)
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     10
              8 LOAD_NAME                2 (z)
        >>   10 UNARY_NOT
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Tested with both, Python 3.6.7 and 2.7.15.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same, there is no difference at all. The standard operator is in fact `not in` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)), the `not 7 in` form will get automatically transformed to `7 not in`.

So the recommended way is `if 7 not in [5, 6, 7]`, that's a straight use of the operator and also has improved readability.