# replace "key" name in whole JSON python for bulk data in efficient way

Tags: json, python-3.x

Actually i am pushing data to other system but before pushing i have to change the "key" in the whole JSON. JSON may contain 200 or 10000 or 250000 data.

sample JSON:

```
{
  "insert": "table",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "testName": "testname",
      "ContactID": 212121
    },
    {
      "testName": "testname",
      "ContactID": 2146354564
       },
    {
      "testName": "testname",
      "ContactID": 12312
        },
    {
      "testName": "testname",
      "ContactID": 211221

    },
    {
      "testName": "testname",
      "ContactID": 10218550

    }
  ]
}
```

I need to change contacts array Keys. These contacts may be in bulk. So i need to work with this efficiently with minimal complexity.

The above JSON to be converted as below

```
{
  "insert": "table",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "testname",
      "phone": 212121
    },
    {
      "name": "testname",
      "phone": 2146354564
       },
    {
      "name": "testname",
      "phone": 12312
        },
    {
      "name": "testname",
      "phone": 211221

    },
    {
      "name": "testname",
      "phone": 10218550

    }
  ]
}
```

here is my code trying by loop

```
ini_dict = request.data
contact_data = ini_dict['contacts']
for i in contact_data: 
    i['name'] = i.pop('testName')
print(contact_data)
```

Please suggest me how can i change the key names efficiently for bulk data. i mean for 50000 lists in contacts. "for loop" will be leading a performance issue. So please let me know the efficient way to achieve this

Comment: What is the problem with the posted code?

Comment: i want to do that replace key for bulk data. i mean 20000/50000 Contacts data

Comment: So your issue here is speed of the process?

Comment: Yes :(  how to do for bulk data without performance issue

Comment: How long is it taking now, and how much faster do you think it should be?

Comment: i didn't checked yet.. But need to be ready with the alternative solution

Comment: The posted code does not even produce the desired results, regardless of how fast it is.

Comment: others said dictnary it then zip and unzip is one way. some other suggested use MAP to achieve in fast way. I need your suggestions so that i can able to move further

Comment: I just ran your code for a 50000 element contact list and it took just `0.023` seconds. Is that not fast enough?

Comment: oh really ? great. How you tested that ?

Comment: By running it. It really isn't very hard. If you make a 50k entry list in a dict, then run the code using something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866380/how-can-i-time-a-code-segment-for-testing-performance-with-pythons-timeit). You should have at least run the code on a "big" dict and observed it being "slow" before writing a question about a hypothetical optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how fast you need it to be nor how you are choosing to store your json. One simple solution is just store it as a string and then replace all the instances of your attributes.

```
# Something like this using a jsonstring

jsonstring.replace("'testName':", "'name':")
jsonstring.replace("'ContactId':", "'phone':")
```

If you want to do this in bulk you, may need to create some batch process to be able to fetch multiple existing records and make changes at once. I have done this before with the java equivalent of https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/ but, that was more for  modifying existing records in a database.