# How would you count time elapsedsince first execution of the loop until ended by user in Python?

Tags: python, time

I'm new to programming in general and this is my first post here, so please explain like I'm five.
This is a random string combination generator (sorry if I don't know how to call it properly) and I want to make the program start counting time since A key is first pressed until Q is pressed, without counting repeats caused by pressing A.
I also know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python/25823885) might come handy, but I don't really know how to make it work.
Here's the code:

```
import random
import os
print('hello world')
while True:
    while True:
        key = msvcrt.getch().lower()
        if key == b'a':
            os.system('cls')

            alpha = random.randint(1, 2)
            bravo = random.randint(1, 2)
            if alpha == 1:
                print('foo')
            elif alpha == 2:
                print('bar')
            if bravo == 1:
                print('spam')
            elif bravo == 2:
                print('eggs')
        elif key == b'q':
            os.system('cls')
            print('elapsed time: mm:ss')   #this is where i want to have shown time elapsed from pressing A for the first time until pressing Q
            break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I time a code segment for testing performance with Pythons timeit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866380/how-can-i-time-a-code-segment-for-testing-performance-with-pythons-timeit)

Answer (score 0):

1. We create `start` uninitialized (as `None`) outside the loop
2. When `a` is pressed, we check if `start` is uninitialized (`if start is None`) 
   2.1. If it is uninitialized. we initialize with current time
3. When `q` is pressed 
   3.1. We check if `start` is initialized (`if start is not None`), (to cover the case that `q` is the first input so we won't do the next step if `start` is uninitialized) 
   3.2. If `start` is initialized we print elapsed time

```
import random
import os
from timeit import default_timer as timer


print('hello world')
start = None
while True:
    while True:
        key = msvcrt.getch().lower()
        if key == 'a':
            # If start time is uninitialized
            if start is None:
                # Initialize start time
                start = timer()
            os.system('cls')
            alpha = random.randint(1, 2)
            bravo = random.randint(1, 2)
            if alpha == 1:
                print('foo')
            elif alpha == 2:
                print('bar')
            if bravo == 1:
                print('spam')
            elif bravo == 2:
                print('eggs')
        elif key == 'q':
            os.system('cls')
            if start is not None:
                end = timer()
                print(f'elapsed time: {end - start}')
            break
```

Comment: does not qoute work as i wished it would, i wouldn't like to change from msvcrt,getch() to input() because it would require me to press A and Enter right after, timing is crucial in what i'm aiming to do. Also, the {end - start} time apparently doesn't show the time from pressing A key for the very first time until loop broken with Q key, or so it seems to me.

Comment: @21214343 Changed back to `msvcrt.getch()`, and switched to another time measurement library

Comment: @21214343 `timeit` will produce far more accurate results since it will automatically account for things like garbage collection and OS differences

Comment: Now it doesn't work, hung on 'hello world'. Doesn't seem to respond in input.

Comment: Very strange, change to `key = input().lower()` just for the sake of testing it. it works fluently on my machine. @21214343