# Which is Faster Counter Python

Tags: python, counter

I wanted to know which one faster counter

1)

```
from threading import Thread
def c(output, i):
    if i in output:
        output[i] += 1
    else:
        output[i] = 1
def build(itera):
    output = {}
    for i in itera:
        Thread(target=c, args=(output, i)).start()
    return output
```

2. 

```
def build(itera):
    output = {}
    for i in itera:
        if i in output:
            output[i] += 1
        else:
            output[i] = 1
    return output
```

3. 

```
from collections import Counter
Counter("12342")
```

And if any code which performs same this but is faster all all three block of code please tell me

Comment: What did you find when you timed them?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866380/how-can-i-time-a-code-segment-for-testing-performance-with-pythons-timeit)

Comment: [Which is faster?—Fabulous adventures in coding](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to figure out which methods takes the least amount of time:

```
import time

start = time.time()

***
 The code you want to test out
***

end = time.time()

time_taken = round(end - start), 2
print(time_taken)
```

The output is in seconds.

---

Using `timeit`:

```
import timeit

def do_something():
  pass

timeit.timeit(f"{do_something()}")
```

Comment: I wanted to use timeit but i cant understand it

Comment: Wait I know how to do that. Btw we have the same name! High five!

Comment: Check the updated answer. I have included a way to use timeit.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your code, and see which runs quicker:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.now()

#code here

end = datetime.now()

total = end - start

print(total.total_seconds())
```